# Need help to configure netplan for two NICs with static IPs on separate networks

Tags: ubuntu, networking, netplan

I've got a new server with a fresh Ubuntu 20.04 LTS install. I've got one interface connected to our main corporate network with a static IP address, and now need to connect a second interface to a separate backline network using a static IP address.

```
172.10.1.0/24 <------> [eno1np0:172.1.1.10] [eno2np1:192.168.1.10] <------> 192.168.1.0/24
public-router           server_NIC_1         server_NIC_2                  backline-router
```

I've been doing network config with /etc/network/interfaces and ifconfig for years, and am stumped by netplan configs. I'm reading docs, and looking at examples and doing trial and error with no success. Here are the contents of `/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml`:

```
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    eno1np0:
      addresses:
      - 172.10.1.10/24
      gateway4: 172.10.1.1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 172.10.1.32
        - 172.10.1.33
        search:
        - mycompany.com
    eno2np1:
      addresses:
      - 192.168.1.10/24
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
  version: 2
```

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

- John

Answer (score 0):

The second NIC's IP address is incorrect. Actually, it's malformed, since it only has three octets:

```
eno2np1:
  addresses:
  - 192.168.10/24
  gateway4: 192.168.1.1
```

I think that `netplan apply` should catch such an error.

Comment: I think it's quite obvious that this part of the netplan configuration doesn't work, but I added some explanation.

Comment: Ah, I pasted the config file contents then "redacted" the IP addresses. That's a typo in the redaction. Fixed now. Is there anything else wrong with the configuration?

Comment: I don't see anything. What makes you think it might be incorrect?

Comment: Well, I was able to get it working briefly with this configuration. Then I rebooted, and couldn't reach the server from either network. I'm teleworking, so had to drive in, restore the backed up config file (just the first interface), and that's what's running now.

Comment: To me, the fact that it worked before rebooting indicates that the config is correct. I would investigate if something is started at reboot that messes with your network.

Answer (score -1):

For years I have battled with linux (esp. ubuntu) where I never got it to work with two default gateways. Typically what I have done is use my main interface with a gateway and other interface with specific routes added. These routes are needed for the return traffic. That works cleanly but its little cumbersome too to maintaining a route table to all the destinations.

I was hoping in ubuntu 20.x this behavior was changed but I guess not.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/445346)